# Readability versus maintainability, special case of writing nested function calls

Tags: c#, c++, coding-style, readability, maintainability

My coding style for nested function calls is the following:

```
var result_h1 = H1(b1);
var result_h2 = H2(b2);
var result_g1 = G1(result_h1, result_h2);
var result_g2 = G2(c1);
var a = F(result_g1, result_g2);
```

I have recently changed to a department where the following coding style is very much in use:

```
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

The result of my way of coding is that, in case of a crashing function, Visual Studio can open the corresponding dump and indicate the line where the problem occurs (I'm especially concerned about access violations).

I fear that, in case of a crash due to the same problem programmed in the first way, I won't be able to know which function has caused the crash.

On the other hand, the more processing you put on a line, the more logic you get on one page, which enhances readability.

Is my fear correct or am I missing something, and in general, which is preferred in a commercial environment? Readability or maintainability?

I don't know if it's relevant, but we are working in C++ (STL) / C#.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: @gnat: you refer to a general question, while I am especially interested in the mentioned case of nested function calls and the consequence in case of crash dump analysis, but thanks for the link, it contains quite some interesting information.

Comment: Note that if this example were to be applied to C++ (as you mention this being used in your project) then this is not only a question of style, as the _order_ of evaluation of the `HX` and `GX` invocations may change in the one-liner, as the order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. If you for some reason depend on the order of side effects (knowingly or unknowingly) in the invocations, this ”style refactoring” could end up effecting more than just readability/maintenance.

Comment: Is the variable name `result_g1` what you'd actually use or does this value actually represent something with a sensible name; e.g. `percentageIncreasePerSecond`. That would actually be my test to decide between the two

Comment: Regardless of your feelings on coding style, you should follow the convention that's already in place unless its clearly wrong (it doesnt seem it is in this case).

Comment: decompose it into at least two smaller functions, give them proper names, and then call that function? This statement can be refactored into one function with three inputs and one output, and can be given a sensible name.

Comment: The stack trace still shows where it crashes, though it might become confusing when, for example, instead of having calls to 3 different function on one line, you have 3 calls to the same function. I tend to use  your style, too, but it's a bit noisier.

Comment: To add to what @dfri said, because the order of evaluation is undefined this can also have implications for exception-safety which you should be aware of before using this form.

Comment: Does C# have no method for function composition/piping? And do crashes not provide a stack trace to figure out where the problematic line is? I admit that having the actual offending line highlighted in your editor is nice, but the trace should tell you where the failure is...

Comment: In case you wonder, one of the downvotes is for the meaningless names in your code.

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339495/at-what-point-is-brevity-no-longer-a-virtue

Comment: @t3chb0t You're free to vote however you like, but please be aware in the interest of encouraging good, useful, on-topic questions on this site (and discouraging bad ones), that the purpose of up or down voting a question is to indicate whether a question is useful and clear, so voting for other reasons such as using a vote as a means to provide criticism on some example code posted to aid the context of the question generally isn't helpful in maintaining the quality of the site:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 128, accepted):

If you felt compelled to expand a one liner like

```
 a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

I wouldn't blame you. That's not only hard to read, it's hard to debug.

Why?

1. It's dense
2. Some debuggers will only highlight the whole thing at once
3. It's free of descriptive names

If you expand it with intermediate results you get

```
 var result_h1 = H1(b1);
 var result_h2 = H2(b2);
 var result_g1 = G1(result_h1, result_h2);
 var result_g2 = G2(c1);
 var a = F(result_g1, result_g2);
```

and it's still hard to read. Why? It solves two of the problems and introduces a fourth:

1. <s>It's dense</s>
2. <s>Some debuggers will only highlight the whole thing at once</s>
3. It's free of descriptive names
4. It's cluttered with non-descriptive names

If you expand it with names that add new, good, semantic meaning, even better! A good name helps me understand.

```
 var temperature = H1(b1);
 var humidity = H2(b2);
 var precipitation = G1(temperature, humidity);
 var dewPoint = G2(c1);
 var forecast = F(precipitation, dewPoint);
```

Now at least this tells a story. It fixes the problems and is clearly better than anything else offered here but it requires you to come up with the names.

If you do it with meaningless names like `result_this` and `result_that` because you simply can't think of good names then I'd really prefer you spare us the meaningless name clutter and expand it using some good old whitespace:

```
int a = 
    F(
        G1(
            H1(b1), 
            H2(b2)
        ), 
        G2(c1)
    )
;
```

It's just as readable, if not more so, than the one with the meaningless result names (not that these function names are that great).

1. <s>It's dense</s>
2. <s>Some debuggers will only highlight the whole thing at once</s>
3. It's free of descriptive names
4. <s>It's cluttered with non-descriptive names</s>

When you can't think of good names, that's as good as it gets.

For some reason [debuggers love new lines](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/4303/1401) so you should find that debugging this isn't difficult:

[image]

If that's not enough, imagine `G2()` was called in more than one place and then this happened:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at composition.Example.G2(Example.java:34)
    at composition.Example.main(Example.java:18)
```

I think it's nice that since each `G2()` call would be on it's own line, this style takes you directly to the offending call in main.

So please don't use problems 1 and 2 as an excuse to stick us with problem 4. Use good names when you can think of them. Avoid meaningless names when you can't.

Lightness Races in Orbit's [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366355/readability-versus-maintainability-special-case-of-writing-nested-function-call/366370#comment799529_366370) correctly points out that these functions are artificial and have dead poor names themselves. So here's an example of applying this style to some code from the wild:

```
var user = db.t_ST_User.Where(_user => string.Compare(domain,  
_user.domainName.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
.Where(_user => string.Compare(samAccountName, _user.samAccountName.Trim(), 
StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0).Where(_user => _user.deleted == false)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

I hate looking at that stream of noise, even when word wrapping isn't needed. Here's how it looks under this style:

```
var user = db
    .t_ST_User
    .Where(
        _user => string.Compare(
            domain, 
            _user.domainName.Trim(), 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        ) == 0
    )
    .Where(
        _user => string.Compare(
            samAccountName, 
            _user.samAccountName.Trim(), 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        ) == 0
    )
    .Where(_user => _user.deleted == false)
    .FirstOrDefault()
;
```

As you can see, I've found this style works well with the functional code that's moving into the object oriented space. If you can come up with good names to do that in intermediate style then more power to you. Until then I'm using this. But in any case, please, find some way to avoid meaningless result names. They make my eyes hurt.

Comment: Whitespace is a great technique (invaluable in SQL for example), but it tends to use the highest number of code lines of all, and it can itself become very subtle to read and very delicate to construct the formatting (unless the IDE works with you). In an imperative language, I would still use an intermediate variable to evaluate `G1`.

Comment: @Steve and I'm not telling you not to. I'm begging for a meaningful name. All to often I've seen the intermediate style done mindlessly. Bad names burn up my brain far more than sparse code per line does.I don't let width or length considerations motivate me to make my code dense or my names short. I let them motivate me to decompose more. If good names just ain't gonna happen consider this work around to avoid meaningless noise.

Comment: Agreed. The only time I would use `G1` would be if I was emulating a standard mathematical equation which used those terms. I might use acronyms for the intermediate variables, based on the names of the functions they called, if it was clear in the context.

Comment: Agree, but (1) `forecast(precipitation(temperature(b1), humidity(b2)), dewPoint(c1))` tells the same story, if you name your function appropriately. (2) Debuggers show the stack trace too, you can identify the scope easily.

Comment: “A debugger is only going to highlight the whole thing at once.” — That very much depends on the debugger. It’s been a while since I used VS (which is presumably what OP uses) but as far as I can remember the debugger deals just fine with subexpressions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well theoretically you're right of course. To which I say: "Pics or it didn't happen!"

Comment: @CandiedOrange [Best I can find in a pinch](https://goo.gl/images/EcUNwp) (note the highlighted sub-expression). In addition [sub-expressions can be inspected/computed](https://goo.gl/images/k6eiYQ) and, IIRC, have break points set on them.

Comment: @KonradRudolph nice! Hmm I think we're taking down 2000things.com with all the traffic. Failing to load.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In your second image, it's only showing the value of `i`, which is a specific variable. I don't think it will show the return value of a function that's not assigned anywhere. You could invoke it via Immediate Window, but if it's an expensive function, you might not want to do that, and for some functions, Immediate Window sometimes just kind of craps out and fails.

Comment: I add to your post: I've got a little rule of thumb: **If you can't name it, it might be a sign that it's not well-defined.**

I use it on entities, properties, variables, modules, menus, helper classes, methods, etc.

In numerous situations this tiny rule has revealed a serious flaw in design.

So in a way, good naming not only contributes to readability and maintainability, it helps you verify the design.

Of course there are exceptions to every simple rule.

Comment: The expanded version looks ugly.  There's *too much*  w h i t e s p a c e  there which r e d u c e s i t s e f f e c t i v e n e s s s i n c e e v e r y t h i n g i s e m p h a s i z e d w i t h i t, m e a n i n g n o t h i n g i s.

Comment: @Alireza that's insightful. I've found other reasons to include a failure of personal vocabulary, name collisions with the same idea expressed in a different way, and a desire for sleep. Names are hard. They are far to easy to neglect but they pay off big when done right.

Comment: I am not a big fan of the expanded version. If you have variable defined it is really easy to log, or put a debug trace around it. When everything happens inside one function call; it is harder to log/debug.

Comment: @Akavall all true but still not worth living with a bad name. Either think of a good one or delete your bad one before checking in. Without a good name you're just checking in debugging code.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq The only extra whitespace there is a couple of newlines and some indentation, and it's all carefully placed at *meaningful* boundaries. Your comment instead places whitespace at non-meaningful boundaries. I suggest you take a slightly closer and more open look.

Comment: I'm all for meaningful names. But, I'm going to assume that our "H" and "G" functions are simply what the asker decided to use for generic methods to explain his question as opposed to "foo" and "bar".

Comment: @jpmc26 My point is that adding too much whitespace within a line of code deemphasizes whitespace between lines of code. Other issues include: looking ugly and 8x less code fitting on the screen. These noteworthy negatives far outweigh the purported positives.

Comment: Unlike @MateenUlhaq I'm on the fence about the whitespace in this particular example with such function names, but with _real_ function names (which are more than two characters in length, right?) it could be what I'd go for.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq What you mention is part of why this post *prefers* good names for intermediate values. But in the absence of them, dense sequences of calls are much more readable when vertical whitespace makes the boundaries more apparent. It's much better to deal with some vertical scrolling than to try to parse that complexity out mentally. Keeping your position while you jumping back and forth between this code and the actual function definitions is also harder with the dense version. And longer names (like Lightness mentions) will probably make the single line spill over the screen width.

Comment: dense is not a bad thing, if the variables and function names involved are descriptive.  These aren't

Comment: People get so focused on the names and forget that maybe, just maybe, askers use generic names (a,b,c,d / x,y,z,w / foo,bar,baz,qux) for their functions and variables because they are creating small code snippets for demonstrating the very specific code properties they ask about?

Comment: @IdanArye If you want to know what I think about motorcycles don't ask me what I think about personal transportation. I work with what you give me.

Comment: @CandiedOrange If I ask for your opinion about a motorcycle, I won't wear you down with the detailed story of my day at the exhibition hall where I saw it, what I had for lunch and what I wore that day. Are you going to assume that just because I omitted these details I hate nothing and wore nothing, and focus on that because me going hungry and being naked in public are more pressing issues than the specifics of some motorcycle?

Comment: @IdanArye I mean if I see it, I focus on it. Showing me a bad name doesn't make me ignore the name. That is pretty much the central thesis of this answer.

Comment: @CandiedOrange But these are not even names - they are just placeholders for names. To have good names you need context, and we don't know the context of that code. We don't know the domain of the project. We don't even know if it's frontend, backend, embedded, script or whatever. The asker did not specify that because it's not relevant - they wanted to focus on the intermediate values versus nested expressions, and constructed a small example.

Comment: I just happened across this again, and I'd like to point out that there's sort of a third option for your final example: create a utility method. E.g. `public static bool TrimmedIgnoreCaseEquals(this string s1, string s2) { return 0 == String.Compare(s1.Trim(), s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); }`. This reduces each line to `Where(_user => _user.domainName.TrimmedIgnoreCaseEquals(domain))` and similar, abstracting away much logic.  I find myself using "utility functions" **very often** to great effect, so you don't necessarily need *variables* to name away intermediate steps.

Comment: @jpmc26 true. but "TrimmedIgnoreCaseEquals()"? I'm all for hiding details with good names that express intent and ensure what you find behind them is no surprise but they should be more than a mash up of other names or structure is all that gets communicated. Semantically meaningful names are much more powerful abstractions that get their idea across without forcing me to stick to a particular implementation.

Comment: @CandiedOrange In an ideal world, sure. In practice, sometimes it's the best you can do, especially with limited time. Even if the function name isn't ideal, moving the logic out is a massive enough readability win that it's still better. I don't really like the name, either, but I haven't thought of a better one. Let me know if you do.

Comment: @jpmc26 the theme of this answer is that if I can't have a good meaningful name I'd rather have well structured white space than meaningless noise.

Comment: @CandiedOrange Well, your preference, but I'd say the name is *meaningful*, even if it's verbose. This often happens with "utility" methods. They don't have any particular meaning within the domain of the problem you're trying to solve, but they having meaning in terms of *programming logic* that you need to implement. Compacting elements of programming logic into single method calls makes the mental abstractions more obvious and allows the domain logic to stand out more, in much the same way intermediate variables do. That's a big win for readability.

Comment: @jpmc26 rather than a public utility function that has no context and so must be this verbose consider a private function localized to this context named `isSame(String expect, String userData)`.

Answer (score 52):

> On the other hand, the more processing you put on a line, the more logic you get on one page, which enhances readability.

I utterly disagree with this. Just looking at your two code examples calls this out as incorrect:

```
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

is heard to read. "Readability" does not mean information density; it means "easy to read, understand and maintain".

Sometimes, the code is simple and it makes sense to use a single line. Other times, doing so just makes it harder to read, for no obvious benefit beyond cramming more onto one line.

However, I'd also call you out on claiming that "easy to diagnose crashes" means code is easy to maintain. Code that doesn't crash is far easier to maintain. "Easy to maintain" is achieved primarily via the code been easy to read and understand, backed up with a good set of automated tests.

So if you are turning a single expression into a multi-line one with many variables just because your code often crashes and you need better debug information, then stop doing that and make the code more robust instead. You should prefer writing code that doesn't need debugging over code that's easy to debug.

Comment: While I agree that `F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1))` is hard to read, this has nothing to do with being crammed too dense. (Not sure if you meant to say that, but it could be interpreted this way.) Nesting three or four functions in a single line can be perfectly readable, in particular if some of the functions are simple infix operators. It is the nondescriptive names that are the problem here, but that problem is even worse in the multi-line version, where _yet more nondescriptive names_ are introduced. Adding only boilerplate almost never aids readability.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: To me, the difficulty is that it's not obvious whether `G1` takes 3 parameters or only 2 and `G2` is another parameter to `F`. I have to squint and count the parentheses.

Comment: @MatthieuM. this can be an issue, though if the functions are well-known it is often obvious which takes how many arguments. Specifically, as I said, for _infix functions_ it's immediately clear that they take two arguments. (Also, the parenthesized-tuples syntax most languages use exacerbates this problem; in a language that prefers Currying it's automatically clearer: `F (G1 (H1 b1) (H2 b2)) (G2 c1)`.)

Comment: Question:  Would you still say it's hard to read if `F`'s arguments were split across lines? `F(<newline>G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)),<newline>G2(c1)<newline>);` (quick edit:  CandiedOrange's answer is a more extreme version of this)

Comment: Personally I prefer the more compact form, as long as there's styling around it like in my prior comment, because it guarantees less state to mentally keep track of - `result_h1` cannot be reused if it doesn't exist, and the plumbing between the 4 variables is obvious.

Comment: I would want to upvote you, except that I'm nitpicky about bs like "Code that doesn't crash is far easier to maintain". I prefer to maintain code that crashes with a clear cause to code that doesn't crash but just delivers a bad end result.

Comment: I too was thinking this was going to be a nice answer but then it went the "just don't write bugs" route, which I can't upvote.

Comment: I have found that code that's easy to debug generally is code that doesn't need debugging.

Comment: @DonFusili:  Count yourself lucky that you have the option to crash.  My tasks aren't allowed to crash, and they aren't allowed to produce garbage either.  They have to deal with bad things gracefully and keep right on running.  They are allowed to complain in the logs so I can find out later what bad thing happened and how my code handled it.

Comment: @JRE I know these coding jobs exist and I do indeed count myself lucky mine isn't one of them. Mad respect to everyone that does thrive in your kind of environment. My comment was on this answer in this context,though. The question clearly indicates that crashing is allowed and as such I don't feel this answer does the situation justice.

Comment: @JRE "they aren't allowed to produce garbage either. They have to deal with bad things gracefully and keep right on running." is a contradiction in itself. You can either keep on running in all situations (throw a big try catch block at the top level and install a few headers) or you can make sure to not cause inconsistencies. There are simply cases where you have to decide for one or the other.

Comment: @marcus Also, what happens if a test fails? Are you _not_ going to debug it?

Answer (score 25):

Your first example, the single-assignment-form, is unreadable because the chosen names are utterly meaningless. That might be an artifact of trying not to disclose internal information on your part, the true code might be fine in that respect, we cannot say. Anyway, it's long-winded due to extremely low information-density, which does not generally lend itself to easy understanding.

Your second example is condensed to an absurd degree. If the functions had useful names, that might be fine and well readable because there isn't *too much* of it, but as-is it's confusing in the other direction.

After introducing meaningful names, you might look whether one of the forms seems natural, or if **there's a golden middle** to shoot for.

Now that you have readable code, most bugs will be obvious, and the others at least have a harder time hiding from you.

Answer (score 22):

As always, when it comes to readability, **failure is in the extremes**. You can take *any* good programming advice, turn it into a religious rule, and use it to produce utterly unreadable code. (If you don't believe me on this, check out these two [IOCCC](//www.ioccc.org/) winners [borsanyi](//www.ioccc.org/2011/borsanyi/hint.html) and [goren](//www.ioccc.org/2011/goren/hint.html) and take a look at how differently they use functions to render the code utterly unreadable. Hint: Borsanyi uses exactly one function, goren much, much more...)

In your case, the two extremes are 1) using single expression statements only, and 2) joining everything into big, terse, and complex statements. Either approach taken to the extreme renders your code unreadable.

Your task, as a programmer, is to **strike a balance**. For every statement you write, it is *your* task to answer the question: "Is this statement easy to grasp, and does it serve to make my function readable?"

---

The point is, there is no single measurable statement complexity that can decide, what is good to be included in a single statement. Take for example the line:

```
double d = sqrt(square(x1 - x0) + square(y1 - y0));
```

This is quite a complex statement, but any programmer worth their salt should be able to immediately grasp what this does. It is a quite well known pattern. As such, it is much more readable than the equivalent

```
double dx = x1 - x0;
double dy = y1 - y0;
double dxSquare = square(dx);
double dySquare = square(dy);
double dSquare = dxSquare + dySquare;
double d = sqrt(dSquare);
```

which breaks the well known pattern into a seemingly meaningless number of simple steps. However, the statement from your question

```
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

seems overly complicated to me, **even though it's one operation less than distance calculation**. Of course, that's a direct consequence of me not knowing anything about `F()`, `G1()`, `G2()`, `H1()`, or `H2()`. I might decide differently if I knew more about them. But that's precisely the problem: The advisable complexity of a statement strongly depends on the context, and on the operations involved. And you, as a programmer, are the one who must take a look at this context, and decide what to include into a single statement. If you care about readability, you cannot offload this responsibility to some static rule.

Answer (score 14):

@Dominique, I think in your question's analysis, you're making the mistake that "readability" and "maintainability" are two separate things.

Is it possible to have code that is maintainable but unreadable? Conversely, if code is extremely readable, why would it become unmaintainable on account of being readable? I've never heard of any programmer who played these factors off against each other, having to choose one or the other!

In terms of deciding whether to use intermediate variables for nested function calls, in the case of 3 variables given, calls to 5 separate functions, and some calls nested 3 deep, I would tend towards using at least *some* intermediate variables to break that down, as you have done.

But I certainly do not go as far as to say function calls must never be nested at all. It's a question of judgment in the circumstances.

I would say the following points bear on the judgment:

1. If the called functions represent standard mathematical operations, they're more capable of being nested than functions which represent some obscure domain logic whose results are unpredictable and cannot necessarily be evaluated mentally by the reader.
2. A function with a single parameter is more capable of participating in a nest (either as an inner or outer function) than a function with multiple parameters. Mixing functions of different arities at different nesting levels is prone to leave code looking like a pig's ear.
3. A nest of functions which programmers are *accustomed* to seeing expressed in a particular way - perhaps because it represents a standard mathematical technique or equation, which has a standard implementation - may be more difficult to read and verify if it is broken down into intermediate variables.
4. A small nest of function calls that performs simple functionality and is already clear to read, and is then broken down excessively and atomised, *is capable of being* more difficult to read than one that was not broken down at all.

Comment: +1 to "Is it possible to have code that is maintainable but unreadable?".  That was my first thought, too.

Answer (score 4):

Both are suboptimal. Consider Comments.

```
// Calculating torque according to Newton/Dominique, 4th ed. pg 235
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

Or specific functions rather than general ones:

```
var a = Torque_NewtonDominique(b1,b2,c1);
```

When deciding which results to spell out, keep in mind cost (copy vs reference, l-value vs r-value), readability, and risk, individually for each statement.

For example, there's no added value from moving simple unit/type conversions onto their own lines, because these are easy to read and extremely unlikely to fail:

```
var radians = ExtractAngle(c1.Normalize())
var a = Torque(b1.ToNewton(),b2.ToMeters(),radians);
```

Regarding your worry of analyzing crash dumps, input validation is usually far more important - the actual crash is quite likely to happen inside these functions rather than the line calling them, and even if not, you don't usually need to be told exactly where things blew up. It's way more important to know where things started to fall apart, than it is to know where they finally blew up, which is what input validation catches.

Comment: Re the cost of passing an arg: There are two rules of optimization. 1) Don’t. 2) (for experts only) Don’t *yet*.

Answer (score 2):

Readability is the major portion of maintainability.  Doubt me?  Pick a large project in a language you don't know (perferably both the programming language and the language of the programmers), and see how you'd go about refactoring it...

I would put readability as somewhere between 80 and 90 of maintainability.  The other 10-20 percent is how amenable it is to refactoring.

That said, you effectively pass in 2 variables to your final function (F).  Those 2 variables are created using 3 other variables.  You'd have been better off passing b1, b2 and c1 into F, if F already exist, then create D that does the composition for F and returns the result. At that point it's just a matter of giving D a good name, and it won't matter which style you use.

On a related not, you say that more logic on the page aids readability.  That is incorrect, the metric isn't the page, it is the method, and the LESS logic a method contains, the more readable it is.

Readable means that the programmer can hold the logic (input, output, and algorithm) in their head.  The more it does, the LESS a programmer can understand it.  Read up on cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: I agree with all what you say about readability. But I don't agree that cracking a logical operation into separate methods, *necessarily* makes it more readable than cracking it into separate lines (both techniques which *can*, when overused, make simple logic less readable, and make the entire program more cluttered) - if you crack things too far into methods, you end up emulating assembly language macros and lose sight of how they integrate as a whole. Also, in this separate method, you would still be faced with the same problem: nest the calls, or crack them into intermediate variables.

Comment: @Steve: I didn't say to always do it, but if you are thinking about using 5 lines to get a single value, there's a good chance that a function would be better.  As for the multiple lines vs complex line: if it's a function with a good name both will work equally well.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, self-documenting code is better for both maintainability and readability, regardless of language.

The statement given above is dense, but "self documenting":

```
double d = sqrt(square(x1 - x0) + square(y1 - y0));
```

When broken into stages (easier for testing, surely) loses all context as stated above:

```
double dx = x1 - x0;
double dy = y1 - y0;
double dxSquare = square(dx);
double dySquare = square(dy);
double dSquare = dxSquare + dySquare;
double d = sqrt(dSquare);
```

And obviously using variable and function names that state their purpose clearly is invaluable.

Even "if" blocks can be good or bad in self-documenting.  This is bad because you cannot easily force the first 2 conditions to test the third ... all are unrelated:

```
if (Bill is the boss) && (i == 3) && (the carnival is next weekend)
```

This one makes more "collective" sense and is easier to create test conditions:

```
if (iRowCount == 2) || (iRowCount == 50) || (iRowCount > 100)
```

And this statement is just a random string of characters, viewed from a self-documenting perspective:

```
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

Looking at the above statement, maintainability is still a major challenge if functions H1 and H2 both alter the same "system state variables" instead of being unified into a single "H" function, because someone eventually will alter H1 without even thinking there is an H2 function to look at and could break H2.

I believe good code design is very challenging because there re no hard-and-fast rules that can be systematically detected and enforced.

Comment: all in all imho it all depends on what the methods are and what therefore the intermediate results are - meaningful steps on the way to the final value or just as in your first example part of a calculation with little meaning on their own. Plus depending on the methods, the domain and what familiarity with the respective meaning of the method names one can expect from a developer reading the code, the one liner gets more or less self explanatory just from the method names.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless if you are in C# or C++, as long as you are in a debug build, a possible solution is wrapping the functions

```
var a = F(G1(H1(b1), H2(b2)), G2(c1));
```

You can write oneline expression, and still get pointed where the problem is simply by looking at the stack trace.

```
returnType F( params)
{
    returnType RealF( params);
}
```

Of course, if case you call the same function multiple times in the same line you cannot know which function, however you can still identify it:

- Looking at function parameters
- If parameters are identical and the function does not have side effects then two identical calls become 2 identical calls etc.

This is not a silver bullet, but a not so bad half-way.

Not to mention that wrapping group of functions can even be more beneficial for readability of the code:

```
type CallingGBecauseFTheorem( T b1, C b2)
{
     return G1( H1( b1), H2( b2));
}

var a = F( CallingGBecauseFTheorem( b1,b2), G2( c1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I read “maintainability” a few times, but there is the ability to debug your code as well. In the multi line code, I can easily set a breakpoint at line 3 and step into G1, if I suspect it has a problem on this particular call. With the multi line statement, no chance.

The counter example using functions sqrt and square, they should be mathematical functions that are used by a 100 million programmers, and just work. No reason to debug anything but the complete expression.

Multiple lines also define an order of calls, and the sheer number of parentheses and commas make things unreadable. And then maybe don’t go to extremes. In the example, one temporary variable for the result of G1 is an improvement from the extremes.